# Is a video card necessary when I have a video capture card?

Tags: video, streaming

I need to process live streaming (video and audio), and I am looking for a really great performance PC. I plan to buy a [video capture card](http://www.viewcast.com/products/osprey-cards), but I wonder if additional video card makes andy difference.

Answer (score 1):

The GPU on the video card could be used to compress the audio and video for transmission if the capture card doesn't have a dedicated processor for this.

Answer (score 0):

Certain capture cards, if used in combination with a video/graphics acceleration card (aka graphics card to you and me), will significantly improve performance. It will enable to you to save a great deal of money by making a less powerful standard x86/amd64 processor acceptable.

This excerpt describes an example of a product (8-in composite video capture card) that benefits from a (Direct3D compatibly) dedicated video card:

> Using the card with other Datapath products:
>   The VisionRGB-E1/E1S captures the data and stores it in an on-board video buffer. This data
>   is then copied using DMA to the host system for display, storage or
>   streaming. When a Datapath graphics card is used, the VisionRGB-E1/E1S
>   transfers the data directly to the graphics card thereby increasing
>   performance. The VisionRGB-E1/E1S sends the relevant portions of each
>   captured image to each display channel and instructs each channel to
>   use its graphics engine to render the data. This fully utilises the
>   hardware and dramatically increases performance. When a Direct3D
>   compatible graphics card is used the data can be transferred direct to
>   the graphics card in a similar manner to the Datapath graphics card
>   with the added benefit of non-tearing captures. When the data is
>   displayed on a non Datapath graphics card, the VisionRGB-E1/E1S sends
>   the data to system memory or direct to the graphics card, dependant on
>   the software used for display.